# If two elements have the same order, then they are at the same conjugacy class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove/Disprove: If two elements have the same order, then they are at the same conjugacy class.

I know the other direction is correct, and it seems to me this one is too. Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a good idea to check small examples. Have you checked any groups of order 3?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_5$ seems like a counter example.... Since it's abelian every element has its own conjugacy class, but they all (except 0) have the same order?

Comment: Non abelian counterexample is the dihedral group of order 8. $D_4$, which has a central and non-central elements of order 2.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson You mean "with more than two elements".

Comment: Yes, I suppose I do :)

Comment: Any Abelian group with more than $2$ elements provides a counterexample, as is implicit in a deleted solution.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: in $S_{9}$ $$(1,2,3) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ (4,5,6)(7,8,9)$$ have the same order, namely $3$, but they are not coniugate because they don't have the same cyclic structure.

Comment: The cyclic structure argument is...not obvious. Just take $S_4$ and then $(12)$ and $(34)$. As these commute they are in different conjugacy classes.

Comment: @user1729: $(1 2)=((1 3)(2 4))\circ (3 4) \circ ((1 3)(2 4))^{-1}$.

Comment: @PavelC Ah, sorry, of course. That said, $S_9$ is still overkill: $(12)$ and $(12)(34)$ work.